# Split a list (numpy array, etc.) into groups of a given length, but keeping the same elements within the same group

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to split a list (numpy array, etc.) into groups of a particular length, but keeping the same elements within the same group, even if group size becomes larger than the specified length.

e.g. if we want groups of `size = 5` for the following list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([5] * 19 + [1] + [4] * 4 + [2] * 4 + [3] * 2)

array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

The output would be preferably a list of indices of the grouped elements:

```
>>> [np.where(x==5), np.where((x == 1) | (x == 4)), \
np.where(x==2), np.where(x==3),]

[(array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
         17, 18]),),
 (array([19, 20, 21, 22, 23]),),
 (array([24, 25, 26, 27]),),
 (array([28, 29]),)]
```

The code would need to be efficient enough to process the list of 50k elements in a reasonable amount of time.

Do you have any ideas on how to proceed? I was trying to experiment with pandas groupby, numpy split and similar functions, but was not able to come up with a viable algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by sorting the array, keeping the sort ordering, and then splitting the array based on the differences between values in the sorted array.

```py
# Sort the input array and return the indices (so that x[indices] is sorted)
indices = np.argsort(x, kind='stable')
sorted_x = x[indices]

# Find the index of the first item of each group
groupStartIndex = np.where(np.insert(sorted_x[1:] != sorted_x[:-1], 0, 0))[0]

# Split the indices in groups
result = np.split(indices, groupStartIndex)
```

The result is the following:

```
[array([19]),
 array([24, 25, 26, 27]),
 array([28, 29]),
 array([20, 21, 22, 23]),
 array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])]
```

The group index arrays are sorted by the value associated to each group (eg. 1 2 3 4 5). You can find the associated values (aka keys) using:

```py
group_values = sorted_x[np.insert(groupStartIndex, 0, 0)]
```

Note that is the items are already packed in the input array (eg. no `[5, 5, 1, 5]`), then you can even skip the `np.argsort` and use `np.arange(x.size)` for the indices.

Comment: This looks promising. I also need to join small groups into bigger ones when possible, so that they become of the target size (size = 5 in the above example). Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

Comment: This part can be done in a separate step. You can use `np.concatenate` to merge the index arrays of several groups. For example: `np.concatenate([result[2], result[4]])`.

Comment: I will just need to automate this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with in case anyone else finds it useful:

```py
def split_groups(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    # Sort the input array and return the indices (so that x[indices] is sorted)
    indices = np.argsort(x, kind='stable')
    sorted_x = x[indices]

    # Find the index of the first item of each group
    groupStartIndex = np.where(np.insert(
        sorted_x[1:] != sorted_x[:-1], 0, 0))[0]

    # Split the indices in groups
    return np.split(indices, groupStartIndex)
```

```py
def len_sort(lst):
    lst.sort(key=len)
    return lst


def combine_groups(array_lst, length):
    """inputs: split_groups - a list of numpy arrays
    output: a list of numpy arrays combined up to a given length
    """
    grouped_lst = []
    sorted_lst = len_sort(array_lst)
    for j, group in enumerate(sorted_lst):
        if j == 0:
            accum = group
        else:
            if len(group) + len(accum) > length:
                grouped_lst.append(accum)
                accum = group
            else:
                # concatenate if array joined length is below a threshold
                accum = np.concatenate([accum, group]) 
    grouped_lst.append(accum)
    return grouped_lst
```

Usage:

```py
>>> split_gr = split_groups(x)
>>> combine_groups(array_lst=split_gr, length=8)
```